# ExactTarget Axis Fault - login failed

Tags: exacttarget

I tried the following link to connect the Enterprise API Service of ExactTarget. I didn't succeed.  I used the following site to implement basic connection to ExactTarget API.

[Connecting to ExactTarget API using Axis 2](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/getting_started_developers_and_the_exacttarget_api/connecting_to_the_api_using_java_and_axis2/)

I get the Following error Log

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Login failed
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
at com.exacttarget.wsdl.partnerapi.PartnerAPIStub.update(PartnerAPIStub.java:3263)
at com.et.phservices.ETPHServices.updateSubscriberToActive(ETPHServices.java:387)
at com.et.client.ETClient.main(ETClient.java:19)
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure your API user has the proper permissions in the platform.  There's an API user flag in the user settings and also some roles/permissions that need to be set depending on the type of SFMC account you have.

[Here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_for_microsoft_dynamics_crm/partners/installation_and_configuration/installation_prerequisites/api_user_in_exacttarget/) are the instructions from the ET/SFMC documentation.

Sidenote:  You'll get a lot more visibility on your ET/SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/), specifically with the [marketing-cloud](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag

Comment: 1.How to know if my existing SFMC account is having required permissions? Looks like my current SFMC account is not having permissions, and as seen from the above error.                                    2. Is there a way we can request explicitly for one?                                                               3.Can you let me know user flag settings..can I set the same in props.xml ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to the documenation.

Comment: followed with instructions - tried to login at https://mc.exacttarget.com and is showing 'Invalid username or password.'  seems my account is not admin account - Salesforce Marketing Cloud administrator account. So, how do I get one? The one that am having might be 'App Center' account.